# Servlet with Database works fine in Eclipse but crashes on server?

Tags: java, servlets, heroku, jdbc

I've hit a wall and I can't get through without help.

I'm trying to do a simple login and registration for my Android app using Java Servlet, and the problem is when I run it locally on Tomcat/Eclipse everything works just fine but when I deploy WAR file with it on Heroku free server, the Database part does not seem to work at all.

I suspect it's a problem with the driver actually but I can't get logs since I connect to it through my Android App.

I deployed my database on freesqldatabase. I placed my sql driver in tomcat directiory and checked a thousand times that's it's in Tomcat libraries. Pretty sure that JDBC Driver causes on problem while being deployed but I can't figure out why, everything is OK with android part of app.

Here's the code of servlet:

```
Connection connection = null;
boolean check = false;
//this part does not work online 

try {
    Class.forName("driver");

    connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://sql7.freesqldatabase.com/sql7112115", "sql7112115", "xxxxxxxxxxx");
    response.getWriter().append("4");
    String query = "select * from userdata where username = ? and pass = ? ";
    response.getWriter().append("5");

    PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(query);
    statement.setString(1, "Sue");
    statement.setString(2, "Pass1");

    ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery();
    check = result.next();
    connection.close();
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    System.out.print("Driver error");
} catch (SQLException e) {
    System.out.print("SQL error");
}

if (check) {
    response.getWriter().append("Login succesful");
} else {
    response.getWriter().append("Login unsuccesful");
}
}
```

Comment: You may want to consider using one of the Heroku MySql database providers, like [JawsDB](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/jawsdb) and following their [docs for using JDBC](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/jawsdb#using-with-java)

Comment: Your exception handing is really bad. Replace `System.out.print(..)` by `throw new ServletException(e)`. You will this way immediately face an error page in browser.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I'm noticing is `Class.forName("driver")`.  Typically you'll want the canonical class name - something like `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for answers! It turned out that Heroku disallows this kind of construct - using JDBC and a third party database due to protect from resources leaks. I installed their database and it works fine!